# Wavesurfer on shopify displays black boxes instead

Tags: javascript, shopify, wavesurfer.js

I am trying to implement a audio player on my shopify store using wavesurfer.js. However, it displays a black box instead of the wave form. I have tested this with a live server, and it is supposed to look like this
[image]

But on shopify this is how it looks
[image]

This is my code. The only thing I changed was that instead of having mp3 files locally, they are on shopify.

```js
import WaveSurfer from 'https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js@7/dist/wavesurfer.esm.js';
        
        
function createItem(name, file){
            
            
            
    const itemDiv = document.createElement("div")
    itemDiv.classList.add("item")
    const rowDiv = document.createElement("div")
    rowDiv.classList.add("row")
    const buttonDiv = document.createElement("div")
    buttonDiv.classList.add("button")
    const buttonElement = document.createElement("i")
    buttonElement.classList.add("fa-solid","fa-play")


    const nameDiv = document.createElement("div")
    nameDiv.classList.add("track-name")
    
    if (nameDiv){
        nameDiv.textContent = name
    }
    document.querySelector(".wave-container").appendChild(itemDiv)
    itemDiv.appendChild(rowDiv)
    rowDiv.appendChild(buttonDiv)
    buttonDiv.appendChild(buttonElement)
    
    const waveContainer = document.createElement("div");
    waveContainer.classList.add("waveFormClass");
    rowDiv.append(waveContainer);

            
    itemDiv.appendChild(nameDiv)
    
    const wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
      container: waveContainer,
      waveColor: '#4F4A85',
      progressColor: '#383351',
      url: `${file}`,
    })
            
    wavesurfer.setOptions({height:30})

            

    wavesurfer.on('interaction', () => {
        wavesurfer.playPause();
        buttonElement.classList.toggle("fa-pause");
        buttonElement.classList.toggle("fa-play");
    })
    buttonElement.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
        wavesurfer.playPause();
        buttonElement.classList.toggle("fa-pause");
        buttonElement.classList.toggle("fa-play");
    })
}   

createItem("The Villain", "The_Villain.mp3")
createItem("The Villain", "The_Villain.mp3")
createItem("The Villain", "The_Villain.mp3")
```

```css
.wave-container {
    padding: 25px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.3);
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 20px;
}

.item{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.waveFormClass{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button{
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.track-name{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin:10px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .wave-container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="wave-container">

    </div>
       

    <script type="module" src="waveScript.js"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```